# Entity Framework Transaction locking database

Tags: database, entity-framework

Db Isolation level is set to `ReadCommitted`.

I did it using:

```
(var trans = _dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))
```

But this is still locking the tables in the db.

I need the values before I run another set of execution but I don’t want to commit the values into DB until all the operation are completed.

```
using (var trans = _dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))
        {
int value=getNewValue(oldvalue);

int someothervalue=DoSomeOtherAction(value);

//Some more methods same like this 

trans.Commit();
return true;
}
catch
    (Exception e)
        {
          trans.Rollback(); 
          _logger.Error(e);
           throw e;
           return false;
        }

// Here is the GetNewValue Method

Public int getNewValue(int oldvalue)
{
 var job = _dbContext.VALUE_DATA.FirstorDefault(x => x.value == oldvalue);
 var someData = new VALUE_DATA();
 someData.status = job.status;          
 someData.Date = job.Date;
 someData.Source = job.Source;
 someData.Start_DT = job.Start_DT;
 someData.End_DT = job.End_DT;
 someData.Notes = job.Notes;
 _dbContext.Set <VALUE_DATA >().Add(someData);
 _dbContext.SaveChanges();
 return someData.ID;
}

// DoSomeOtherAction Method 

Public int DoSomeOtherAction(int value)
{   
 var job = _dbContext.SOME_TABLE.FirstorDefault(x => x.value == value);
 var someValue = new SOME_TABLE();
 someValue.Name=job.Name;
 someValue.Address=job.Address;
_dbContext.Set <SOME_TABLE >().Add(someValue);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
 Return someValue.ID;
}
```

Comment: can you please give more details about your problem

Comment: you are setting the readuncommitted only for one transaction and not the whole database ?!

Comment: Yes, I am trying to set the ReadUncommitted only for the particular Transaction not for the whole DB. Is it possible?

Comment: please explain the problem in a better way otherwise this issues will be closed without any answer! and I can help u

Comment: Here is what I am trying to do. I need the values before I run another set of execution but I don’t want to commit the values into DB until all the operation are completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the clasic way to solve the problem:

```
var transactionOptions = new System.Transactions.TransactionOptions();

// change the leavel to Read Uncommited
transactionOptions.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted;

// Use the TransactionScope!
using (var transactionScope = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope(
    System.Transactions.TransactionScopeOption.Required, 
    transactionOptions)
)

using (var _dbContext= new MyDbContext())
{
    // Do your work here!
    transactionScope.Complete();
}
```

If you have other threads which are changing the used table then you might be became a dirty read problem!

Alternatively, you can used DbCommandInterceptor to andding "NOCHECK" to the Sql query.

Comment: bad news something locking your database other threaqd or other transcation ? @MuthuAnnamalai but it should be working! if everything is clean

Comment: Thanks for following up, actually no other thread is running to lock the tables...

Comment: It was not locking the db when i was pulling other data. when i was trying to do select on the data which was inside transaction and never committed was locking . but when i used select (nolock) it worked.

Comment: ^^ oh finally the problem is found and fixed Im happy to hear that